# Generic example not compiling?

Tags: java, generics

Having following example:

```
public class A<S> {
  public S id;
}

public class B extends A<String> {
  B(){
    this.id = "";
  }
}

public class C<K> extends B {
  public K property;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new C().id.substring(0,1));
  }
}
```

`new C().id.substring(0,1)` would not compile because id is of type Object it says.

Whats wrong and is there a way to do this without casting ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: The same code compiles for me and then moving the main() method to classA even runs it with a index out of bounds exception as expected.

Comment: First of all, you need some code to restructure, best practice to have main method in a public class, still this looks right, and code compiled successfully with IndexOutOfBoundException because of blank string.

Comment: @KDM which compiler are you using where it succeeds?

Comment: JDK1.8.0_172 in eclipse.

Comment: Oh sure bad example just copied all in one. lets assume all classes are in own  files and public. IDEA JDK 1.8 compiler could not compile this

Comment: @KDM I suspect that this is a bug in the eclipse compiler. See my answer.

Comment: @AndyTurner you are right. `javac` throws an error and I understand why :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant section of the language spec for raw types is [JLS Sec 4.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) is:

Specifically:

> The superclasses (respectively, superinterfaces) of a raw type are the erasures of the superclasses (superinterfaces) of any of the parameterizations of the generic type.

So, the superclasses of raw `C` are `B` and raw `A`, even though the superclass of `B` is `A<String>`. (This makes my head hurt somewhat).

The next paragraph says:

> The type of a constructor (§8.8), instance method (§8.4, §9.4), or non-static field (§8.3) of a raw type C that is not inherited from its superclasses or superinterfaces is the raw type that corresponds to the erasure of its type in the generic declaration corresponding to C.

So, the type of the `id` field is the erasure of `S`, i.e. `Object`.

As ever, the fix here is [*don't use raw types*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2770321/3788176).

```
System.out.println(new C<>().id.trim());
                     // ^^ Can use any relevant type here, but diamond operator works too
```